# SQL Server see which time is greater

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to pull the time from a field in an existing table which is stored as SMALLDATETIME.

An example of the value stored is as follows:

```
Jun  4 1900 11:30AM
```

I need to grab the time part (hours and minutes) and see if it is less than whatever the current time is now.

```
EG IF @CutoffTime < @CurrentTime THEN
BEGIN
....
END
```

Is there an easy way to do this in SQL Server?
Thanks!

Comment: What is `CurrentTime`? Can you sample data and an expected result? I guess you can cast to `TIME`.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the `datetime` to a time, along with the time from `getutcdate()`, and compare:

```
DECLARE @timeA SMALLDATETIME;

SET @timeA = 'Jun  4 1900 11:30AM'

IF CAST(@timeA AS TIME) < CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS TIME)
BEGIN

  PRINT 'Time earlier than current time'

END
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks to be it. Cheers!

Comment: No problem! If you are no longer looking for additional help with the question, please consider accepting the answer :)